# willpaginate plugin vs jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering whether it is a good idea to refactor my Rails code from Rails Willpaginate to JQuery datatables as I am finding it takes lot of time to code Sorting, Ajaxing the calls, Exporting to CSV/Excel etc.

Any experience so far from others about datatables? Do you recommend to go for it with Rails?

Thanks,
Arshad

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Datatables work out of the box independent from a rails app. If you have a lot of rows you might consider to sort them on the server side.

Here is a example for a PHP integration that you might use for orientation for your ruby implementation:
http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

This is a rails plugin for datatables:
https://github.com/phronos/rails_datatables

So you can perfectly use will_paginate for tables you cover with datatables via ajaxsource.

KR